# When to use $f$ and when $\nu$ signifying frequency?

Tags: frequency, notation, terminology

When to use $f$ and when $\nu$ signifying frequency? I guess that when you mean frequency of electromagnetic wave, you use $\nu$, and $f$ otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those notations are equivalent and are interchangeably used for the same quantity.  Still, $f$ is more commonly used in engineering sciences, while $\nu$ is preferred by physicists.

Comment: Just a note: there are also local specifics, in some languages one or the other notation is more preferred...

Comment: Could you provide any example of such localisation? It sounds rather interesting. I always assumed what your answer states, that we physicists prefer $\nu$.

Comment: @AlfredoHernández I have few books on physics in Slovenian, and they usually use $f$.

Answer (score 2):

In any work, you should pick a convention and stick to it.

In my own work, I typically use $f$ for audio frequencies and $\nu$ for optical frequencies, both in Hz.  I use $\omega$ for the angular frequency $\omega = 2\pi f$.

Comment: I use the same convention. I think $\nu$ is preferred for only optical. $f$ is generally used for audio and oscillatory(AC circuits, pendulums, etc) frequencies. But there's no hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: If you have a textbook that covers all areas, optical as well as oscillatory, usualy one convention is used.  E.g. Serway consistently use $f$, perhaps because it is a book intended for engineers.  Too bad there is no notation convention, comparable to SI units.